# After assigning azure VM public IP (PIP) it is not updated in portal

Tags: azure, ilpip

I have got a linux VM in azure with dynamic IP assigned. As I run a web application in that server, I wanted to assign a ILPIP to it.
I reserved a new PIP to an existing VM using `Get-AzureVM -ServiceName <servicename> -Name <vmname> | Set-AzurePublicIP -PublicIPName <ipname> | Update-AzureVM.`

When checked using `Get-AzureRole -ServiceName <servicename> -Slot Production -InstanceDetails`, the vm is shown with the new public IP address, but the new IP is not shown in the portal, and the status of IP assignment in the VM is still shown as dynamic. Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you trying to use Reserved IP? A classic reserved IP can only assign to a cloud service. The PowerShell command you are using is not assigning a reserved IP to a VM, it's assigning an Instance IP address. If you don't assign a Reserved IP to your cloud service, the Virtual IP address is always Dynamic. And, after you execute the above command, the public IP can be found in Azure Portal under Instance IP address. Please Clarify what you really want to do in your question.

Comment: Please check the question. It is possible to assign a reserved IP to VM level. The answer below is correct. You could refer [this](http://clemmblog.azurewebsites.net/convert-existing-dynamic-vip-reserved-ip-addresses-azure/)

Comment: I see what you need. You want to use reserved IP as ILPIP. I don't know why you accept @AlexBelotserkovskiy's answer. I have check some docs and found out that ILPIP with reserved IP is only doable through cloud service configuration file. I will provide a detailed answer later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute PowerShell commandlets:

```
$cs = Get-AzureService -ServiceName "totestubuntu1"
New-AzureReservedIP -ReservedIPName "ipname2" `
    -Location "East US" -ServiceName $cs.ServiceName
```

You will get Reserved state and Reserved Public IP for your VM exposed to the world.

[image]

Comment: It makes the IP address as reserved and I can see it on portal, but `Get-AzureRole -ServiceName <servicename> -Slot Production -InstanceDetails` still shows another IP as Public IP Address. Can't I have the same IP in both places?

Comment: The Public IP Address you are getting from `Get-AzureRole -ServiceName <servicename> -Slot Production -InstanceDetails` is ILPIP, and the reserved IP address is used as VIP. ILPIP and VIP are 2 different things. Please checked [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-instance-level-public-ip/). They can not be the same.

Comment: I've referred the document already, but the VIP should bound with a port to specify the VM. You are right on the VIP concept, but for my consistent IP, I'd accept the above suggestion. ILPIP is not really required for my current deployment. I need to filter the port access, so VIP seems to be better solution.

Comment: Well, since you are switching strategy, I am not going to provide another answer. I am not so satisfied by the solution I found, anyway. It's involved with worker role instead of classic VM.